# How do I improve the client-rendered content for SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, server-side-rendering

I have a website with many links on it. Some of the links are user generated.

For instance:

1. `example.com/?some_information`
2. `example.com/?some_other_information`

The page will utilize the parameter to render different results by pure JavaScript code. That'd be very convenient and fast because there are millions of varieties of the situation.

The problem is that since the pages are all rendered on the client-side, search bots will regard them as pages with duplicated `H1`, `title`, and all kinds of `meta` tags.

Is there any suggestion to improve a website like this without involving server-side rendering?

Comment: How does your client side router code work?  How does it know which content to show?  What happen if there is no content that matches the URL?

Comment: Does [ Google search console > URL inspection > View Tested Page > Screen Shot ] render the content? I've not tested a pure javascript page for a long time ... last time I did any unique terms on the rendered content where found in search. I would suggest example.com/?page=some_information and example.com?page=other info ... and maybe even change the title and look at [  Google search console > URL inspection > Coverage > Google selected canonical ] without the user friendly URLs for indexing -- example.com/information or example.com /other_information -- canonization and may become difficult.

Comment: On the flip side related to my first comment ... attempting to not have content indexed by using javascript to render the content for the user did not work for me many years ago. I forget my use case, I think it was statistics or something of that nature, which was subject to change? May have been a promotional advert? It was something for human visitors only which was not desired to be searchable. ------ things may have changed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have a fallback design. If the content provided by the URL is invalid, the page will just display default content. I use the `window.location` or `URLSearchParams` to extract the data.